# How to deploy Oracle Service Bus projects via scripts?

Tags: weblogic12c, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-service-bus

I'm attempting to deploy an oracle service bus project to my locally hosted weblogic 12c server in an internet-restricted VM but the tools are indicating my JAR file isn't a valid application file. What is the proper way of building and deploying OSB projects to the weblogic host?

I've attempted to build use both the configjar utility to create jar files as well as exported directly from JDeveloper to a jar file. I've also attempted to use the ant task jwsc to build the osb project, but haven't been successful.

I've attempted to deploy via the deploy() WLST command, the wldeploy ANT task, and the the wldeploy utility tool but they run into an error and quit. I am able to take the .jar file and manually upload it through the service bus console without issue, though.

```
connect(username, password, adminUrl)
deploy(deploymentName,deploymentFile,targets=deploymentTarget)
startApplication(deploymentName)
```

I was expecting that the above sample code would deploy the application successfully, but instead the following error code is returned every time:

> Deployment Message : weblogic.management.DeploymentException:
>   [J2EE:160177]The application at
>   "C:\jdeveloper\mywork\CommonServicesOSB\CrmConnections\test3.jar" was
>   not recognized as a valid application type. If this is an EAR file,
>   please ensure the META-INF/application.xml exists. EJB-JARs should
>   have a META-INF/ejb-jar.xml or corresponding annotations exist. If
>   this is an exploded WAR, the name of directory must be end with
>   ".war". RARs require a META-INF/ra.xml. A JMS deployment should be an
>   XML file whose name ends with "-jms.xml". A JDBC deployment should be
>   an XML file whose name ends with "-jdbc.xml". For other application
>   types, consult the WebLogic Server documentation.

I'm guessing that I'm missing a crucial file or step, but the documentation I can find hasn't made this any clearer. Does anyone know how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Weblogic 11c i used the following script.
Command to run script:

./oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh script.py import.properties path_jar.jar

```
from java.util import HashMap
from java.util import HashSet
from java.util import ArrayList
from java.io import FileInputStream

from com.bea.wli.sb.util import Refs
from com.bea.wli.config.customization import Customization
from com.bea.wli.sb.management.importexport import ALSBImportOperation

import sys

#=======================================================================================
# Entry function to deploy project configuration and resources
#        into a ALSB domain
#=======================================================================================

def importToALSBDomain(importConfigFile, importJarPath):
    try:
        SessionMBean = None
        print 'Loading Deployment config from :', importConfigFile
        exportConfigProp = loadProps(importConfigFile)
        adminUrl = exportConfigProp.get("adminUrl")
        importUser = exportConfigProp.get("importUser")
        importPassword = exportConfigProp.get("importPassword")

        #importJar = exportConfigProp.get("importJar")
        customFile = exportConfigProp.get("customizationFile")

        passphrase = exportConfigProp.get("passphrase")
        project = exportConfigProp.get("project")

        connectToServer(importUser, importPassword, adminUrl)

        print 'Attempting to import :', importJarPath, "on ALSB Admin Server listening on :", adminUrl

        theBytes = readBinaryFile(importJarPath)
        print 'Read file', importJarPath
        sessionName = createSessionName()
        print 'Created session', sessionName
        SessionMBean = getSessionManagementMBean(sessionName)
        print 'SessionMBean started session'
        ALSBConfigurationMBean = findService(String("ALSBConfiguration.").concat(sessionName), "com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.ALSBConfigurationMBean")
        print "ALSBConfiguration MBean found", ALSBConfigurationMBean
        ALSBConfigurationMBean.uploadJarFile(theBytes)
        print 'Jar Uploaded'

        if project == None:
            print 'No project specified, additive deployment performed'
            alsbJarInfo = ALSBConfigurationMBean.getImportJarInfo()
            alsbImportPlan = alsbJarInfo.getDefaultImportPlan()
            alsbImportPlan.setPassphrase(passphrase)
            alsbImportPlan.setPreserveExistingEnvValues(true)
            importResult = ALSBConfigurationMBean.importUploaded(alsbImportPlan)
            SessionMBean.activateSession(sessionName, "Complete test import with customization using wlst")
        else:
            print 'ALSB project', project, 'will get overlaid'
            alsbJarInfo = ALSBConfigurationMBean.getImportJarInfo()
            alsbImportPlan = alsbJarInfo.getDefaultImportPlan()
            alsbImportPlan.setPassphrase(passphrase)
            operationMap=HashMap()
            operationMap = alsbImportPlan.getOperations()
            print
            print 'Default importPlan'
            printOpMap(operationMap)
            set = operationMap.entrySet()

            alsbImportPlan.setPreserveExistingEnvValues(true)

            #boolean
            abort = false
            #list of created ref
            createdRef = ArrayList()

            for entry in set:
                ref = entry.getKey()
                op = entry.getValue()
                #set different logic based on the resource type
                type = ref.getTypeId
                if type == Refs.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TYPE or type == Refs.SERVICE_PROVIDER_TYPE:
                    if op.getOperation() == ALSBImportOperation.Operation.Create:
                        print 'Unable to import a service account or a service provider on a target system', ref
                        abort = true
                elif op.getOperation() == ALSBImportOperation.Operation.Create:
                    #keep the list of created resources
                    createdRef.add(ref)

            if abort == true :
                print 'This jar must be imported manually to resolve the service account and service provider dependencies'
                SessionMBean.discardSession(sessionName)
                raise

            print
            print 'Modified importPlan'
            printOpMap(operationMap)
            importResult = ALSBConfigurationMBean.importUploaded(alsbImportPlan)

            printDiagMap(importResult.getImportDiagnostics())

            if importResult.getFailed().isEmpty() == false:
                print 'One or more resources could not be imported properly'
                raise

            #customize if a customization file is specified
            #affects only the created resources
            if customFile != None :
                print 'Loading customization File', customFile
                print 'Customization applied to the created resources only', createdRef
                iStream = FileInputStream(customFile)
                customizationList = Customization.fromXML(iStream)
                filteredCustomizationList = ArrayList()
                setRef = HashSet(createdRef)

                # apply a filter to all the customizations to narrow the target to the created resources
                for customization in customizationList:
                    print customization
                    newcustomization = customization.clone(setRef)
                    filteredCustomizationList.add(newcustomization)

                ALSBConfigurationMBean.customize(filteredCustomizationList)

            SessionMBean.activateSession(sessionName, "Complete test import with customization using wlst")

        print "Deployment of : " + importJarPath + " successful"
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
        if SessionMBean != None:
            SessionMBean.discardSession(sessionName)
        raise

#=======================================================================================
# Utility function to print the list of operations
#=======================================================================================
def printOpMap(map):
    set = map.entrySet()
    for entry in set:
        op = entry.getValue()
        print op.getOperation(),
        ref = entry.getKey()
        print ref
    print

#=======================================================================================
# Utility function to print the diagnostics
#=======================================================================================
def printDiagMap(map):
    set = map.entrySet()
    for entry in set:
        diag = entry.getValue().toString()
        print diag
    print

#=======================================================================================
# Utility function to load properties from a config file
#=======================================================================================

def loadProps(configPropFile):
    propInputStream = FileInputStream(configPropFile)
    configProps = Properties()
    configProps.load(propInputStream)
    return configProps

#=======================================================================================
# Connect to the Admin Server
#=======================================================================================

def connectToServer(username, password, url):
    connect(username, password, url)
    domainRuntime()

#=======================================================================================
# Utility function to read a binary file
#=======================================================================================
def readBinaryFile(fileName):
    file = open(fileName, 'rb')
    bytes = file.read()
    return bytes

#=======================================================================================
# Utility function to create an arbitrary session name
#=======================================================================================
def createSessionName():
    sessionName = String("SessionScript"+Long(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString())
    return sessionName

#=======================================================================================
# Utility function to load a session MBeans
#=======================================================================================
def getSessionManagementMBean(sessionName):
    SessionMBean = findService("SessionManagement", "com.bea.wli.sb.management.configuration.SessionManagementMBean")
    SessionMBean.createSession(sessionName)
    return SessionMBean

# IMPORT script init
try:
    # import the service bus configuration
    # argv[1] is the export config properties file
    importToALSBDomain(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])

except:
    print "Unexpected error: ", sys.exc_info()[0]
    dumpStack()
    raise
```

and with the following import.properties file:

```
##################################################################
# OSB Admin Configuration                              #
##################################################################
adminUrl=t3://localhost:7001
importUser=weblogic
importPassword=weblogic89
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your sample script! I had to add the following jars to the java classpath, but otherwise this worked without a hitch

CLASSPATH=%OSB_HOME%/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.configfwk.jar;%OSB_HOME%/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.kernel-api.jar;%OSB_HOME%/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.configfwk.jar;%OSB_HOME%/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.configfwk-wls.jar;%OSB_HOME%/lib/modules/oracle.servicebus.kernel-wls.jar;%WLS_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.jar"